# Build a reusable factory angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

After I decided that $resource was not my thing, I wanted to write my own factory to play with my data. Having half written this first one, I am now trying to figure out the best way to reuse this code or my different restful objects. Should I wrap up the code below in a service where I define url and key and then create individual factories that use the service? Or do I put a factory inside a factory? I guess my end result is that I want to be able to create my factories where I define 'object' and 'key'.

```
app.factory('AssignmentData', function($http, apiUrl){
    var object = 'assignments'
    var key = 'assignmentid';
    var url = apiUrl + object + '/';
    var actions = {
        query : function(params){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
                params: params
            }).then(function(response){return response.data},
                    function(error){return error})
        },
        get : function(params){
            return $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: url + params[key],
                        params: _.omit(params, key)
                    }).then(function(response){return response.data},
                            function(error){return error})          
        },
        save : function(object){
            return true;
        },
        delete : function(object){
            return true;
        }       
    }

    return actions;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I asked my question correctly. It probably had nothing to do with angularjs and was just my not knowing how to write javascript. In the end, i wrote my factory as follows which accomplished my goal (or at least I think it did)

```
schedApp.factory('RestData', function($http, apiUrl){

    var resource = function(object){

        var url = apiUrl + object +'s';
        var key = object + 'id';
        var id = 'id';

        var actions = {
            query : function(params){
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    params: params
                }).then(function(response){return response.data},
                        function(error){return error})
            },
            get : function(params){
                return $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: url + '/' params[key],
                            params: _.omit(params, key)
                        }).then(function(response){return response.data},
                                function(error){return error})          
            },
            save : function(object){
                return true;
            },
            delete : function(object){
                return true;
            }       
        }

        return actions;

    }

    return resource;
});
```